# Error while running GR-Radar Block: RuntimeError: logger_set_level: Bad level type

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, gnu, gnuradio, ham-radio

I am currently trying to generate FMCW radar signal using Signal Generator FMCW block from GR-Radar. After I connected it with FMCOMMS4 Sink block, I got this error:

```
RuntimeError: logger_set_level: Bad level type.
```

Can someone help me how to solve this?
Thank you

Best regards,
Edwar

This is the screenshot of my block system and the error from my GNU Radio window [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xXCa.png)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? You've tagged two different ones.